# Как заставить button при нажатии не моргать

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется код Xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Button.FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Margin" Value="2" />
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter"> 
               <EventTrigger.Actions> 
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                             Duration="0:0:1" To="500" AutoReverse="False" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                             Duration="0:0:2" To="80" AutoReverse="False" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Background="White" >
    <Button x:Name="button1" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Кнопка 1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Как деактивировать анимацию моргания кнопки при её нажатии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте нарисовать новый стиль кнопке, покопайте в сторону Expression Blend 4, например.

Answer (score 4):

Моргание происходит из-за изменения цвета при наведении курсора на кнопку. Это легко исправить немного подправив шаблон.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Button.FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!--Вот здесь нужно изменить цвет, я поставил черный с 80% заливкой-->
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#CC000000"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:1" To="500" AutoReverse="False" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:2" To="80" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```